# How to discritize a function domain (break xy-plane to a grid/mesh of squares with vertex values for evaluation)?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, list-manipulation, data-structures, matlab, discretization

I wrote a code using MATLAB to discritize a function's 2D domain into squares/rectangles, whose vertex data (x,y) I can use to evaluate the function at. Then I sum these values over all vertices to evaluate the area integral I need.
I have been struggling to do the same with Mathematica, which I prefer because it is easier to use analytical functions with. To my understanding, the Mathematica alternative for MATLAB for loops is Table[], but I cannot seem to create the structure I need.

In MATLAB, the following function meshsq() generates the mesh I need, and eval() calculates the quantity I need over each point:

```matlab
function mesh = meshsq(m,n)
    % m determines # of segments in x direction, n in y direction.

    kx = linspace(-1,1,m+1); % choose the domain/square ==> x x y: [-1,1]x[-1,1]
    ky = linspace(-1,1,n+1);

    % Assign points to rectangles:
    mesh = zeros(m,n,4,2);
    for i = 1:1:m
        for j = 1:1:n
            mesh(i,j,1,:) = [kx(i),ky(j)];
            mesh(i,j,2,:) = [kx(i+1),ky(j)];
            mesh(i,j,3,:) = [kx(i+1),ky(j+1)];
            mesh(i,j,4,:) = [kx(i),ky(j+1)];
        end
    end

end
```

Then, in a separate function, I extract each vertex's coordinates above and assign a value of a different function (essentially using a difference method):

```matlab
function [c,c2,mes] = eval(q,m,n) % q is some input parameter
    mes = meshsq(m,n); % previous function
    c = zeros(m,n);
    c2 = zeros(m,n);
    for i=1:1:m
        for j = 1:1:n
            % F,G are some functions calculating values for given x,y
            H = F(q,mes(i,j,1,1),mes(i,j,1,2)); 
            psi1 = G(H);
            H = F(q,mes(i,j,2,1),mes(i,j,2,2));
            psi2 = G(H);
            H = F(q,mes(i,j,3,1),mes(i,j,3,2));
            psi3 = G(H);
            H = F(q,mes(i,j,4,1),mes(i,j,4,2));
            psi4 = G(H);
            % These U below are complex numbers:
            U1 = (psi2'*psi1)/(norm(psi2'*psi1)); 
            U2 = (psi3'*psi2)/(norm(psi3'*psi2));
            U3 = (psi4'*psi3)/(norm(psi4'*psi3));
            U4 = (psi1'*psi4)/(norm(psi1'*psi4));
            % The end goal is to calculate the following two quantities at each grid point, for visualization later using meshc(), contourf(), etc. Or, the 'area integral' would be given by summing over all entries.
            c(i,j) = angle(U1*U2*U3*U4);
            c2(i,j) = angle(U1)+angle(U2)+angle(U3)+angle(U4);
        end
    end

end
```

While I tried to do this by making a Table[] inside a Table[] in Mathematica, the issue was that it wasn't clear to me what the necessary data structures are, as the final values I need are c and c2. I think I got the idea of arrays wrong in Mathematica.

So, any advice on how I should think about implementing this using Mathematica? Or any in-build features/tricks that I am not aware of? I could not find similar questions on here.

Comment: What does "discritize " mean? I don't find it in my ABBY Lingvo x6.

Comment: @user64494 I meant something like: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization. My goal is to do a very complicated integral over an area by breaking the area down into a mesh/grid and then evaluating some functions at each grid point. The idea is that Stoke’s Theorem accurately gives line integrals following from this discretization, that in turn corresponds to the area integral.

Comment: Mathematica has functions for generating rectangular lattices in the xy-plane. Look at [`CoordinateBoundsArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBoundsArray.html) and [`CoordinateBoundingBoxArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBoundingBoxArray.html)

Comment: @m_goldberg, thanks. I used your comment to post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @m_goldberg's comment, I figured it out. 
Essentially, I use `CoordinateBoundsArray[]` to make the mesh, and `Apply[]` to evaluate the function at each point.
Following the notation in my MATLAB code above:

```
    bounds = {{-1,1}, {-1,1}};
    mesh = CoordinateBoundsArray[bounds, {Into[m], Into[n]}];
    F[kx_, ky_] := kx^2 + ky^2
    psis = Apply[F, mesh, {2}] // N;
```